# Update value in form array using patchValue

Tags: angular, forms, formarray

I am trying to update value in formArray using patchValue but in some condition, example:

formArray :

```
0: {id: 12, start_time: "17:11", end_time: "17:41", name: "AUB Medical Center"}
1: {id: 15, start_time: "17:58", end_time: "18:03", name: "Sanayeh"}
```

I want to change start_time in object 1.

So i need to use this : `this.locationForm.patchValue(newValueOfStartTime);`

Here i can't assign to patchValue what id of object i want to change and what parameter!

Any suggest?

Comment: Angular has [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#updating-parts-of-the-data-model) on how to do that.

Comment: thank for the documentation. helped me a lot @R.Richards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign value as follows

```
this.locationForm[index].get('start_time').setValue(newValueOfStartTime);
```

Comment: that great but, if i have 3 object in array how can i assign second object? and what at(index) do ?

Comment: @MohamadAbbas Please share the code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular)

Comment: only i need to add : this.locationForm.at(index).patchValue...

Comment: @MohamadAbbas updated the solution with another approach

Answer (score 0):

that it!

```
 this.locationForm.at(index).patchValue({
       start_time: newValueOfStartTime
    });
```